# Generating Dynamic Controls in C# windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms

My GUI looks like the one below. 
[GUI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDvJq.png)

On click of generate Button I am taking all the inputs from the GUI and creating and xml file for it.
My Code to generate Xml file below

```
namespace ActionSample
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class TestCase
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TestCaseID")]
        public string TestCaseID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TestCaseDescription")]
        public string TestCaseDescription { get; set; }
        // public Action Action;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TestSetup")]
        public TestSetup TestSetup { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TestExecution")]
        public TestExecution TestExecution { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestSetup
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Action")]
        public Action Action { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TestStep")]
    public class TestStep
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsExecutable")]
        public bool IsExecutable { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "RequestEndpoint")]
        public string RequestEndpoint { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Action")]
        public Action Action { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TestExecution")]
    public class TestExecution
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TestStep")]
        public TestStep TestStep { get; set; }
    }

    public class Action
    {
        public string ActionCommand;
        public string TimeOut;
        public string BamSymbol;
        public string Side;
        public string PrimeBroker;
        public string Size;
        public string PMCode;
        public string Strategy;
        public string SubStrategy;
        public string ActionLogEndPoint;
        public string ParameterName;
        public string ParameterValue;
        public bool IsActionResultLogged;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ValidationStep")]
        public ValidationStep ValidationStep { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ValidationStep")]
    public class ValidationStep
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsValidated")]
        public bool IsValidated { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ValidationFormat")]
        public string ValidationFormat { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ResponseEndpoint")]
        public string ResponseEndpoint { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ResponseParameterName")]
        public string ResponseParameterName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ResponseParameterValue")]
        public string ResponseParameterValue { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ExpectedValue")]
        public string ExpectedValue { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsValidationResultLogged")]
        public bool IsValidationResultLogged { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ValidationLogEndpoint")]
        public string ValidationLogEndpoint { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestCase));            
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("Action.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 2;

        TestCase tc = new TestCase();
        Action actionObj = new Action();
        TestSetup testsetupObj = new TestSetup();
        ValidationStep vsObj = new ValidationStep();
        TestStep teststepObj = new TestStep();
        TestExecution teObj = new TestExecution();

        actionObj.ActionCommand = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
        actionObj.TimeOut = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        actionObj.BamSymbol = textBox2.Text.ToString();
        actionObj.Side = comboBox4.Text.ToString();
        actionObj.PrimeBroker = comboBox5.Text.ToString();
        actionObj.Size = textBox5.Text.ToString();
        actionObj.PMCode = comboBox2.Text.ToString();
        actionObj.Strategy = textBox7.Text.ToString();
        actionObj.SubStrategy = comboBox3.Text.ToString();
        actionObj.ActionLogEndPoint = textBox9.Text.ToString();

        tc.TestCaseID = textBox4.Text.ToString();
        tc.TestCaseDescription = textBox6.Text.ToString();
        //tc.Action = actionObj;

        teststepObj.IsExecutable = Convert.ToBoolean(textBox17.Text.ToString());
        teststepObj.RequestEndpoint = textBox18.Text.ToString();

        vsObj.IsValidated = Convert.ToBoolean(textBox8.Text.ToString());
        vsObj.ValidationFormat = textBox10.Text.ToString();
        vsObj.ResponseEndpoint = textBox11.Text.ToString();
        vsObj.ResponseParameterName = textBox12.Text.ToString();
        vsObj.ResponseParameterValue = textBox13.Text.ToString();
        vsObj.ExpectedValue = textBox14.Text.ToString();
        vsObj.IsValidationResultLogged = Convert.ToBoolean(textBox15.Text.ToString());
        vsObj.ValidationLogEndpoint = textBox16.Text.ToString();
        actionObj.ValidationStep = vsObj;
        testsetupObj.Action = actionObj;
        teststepObj.Action = actionObj;
        teObj.TestStep = teststepObj;
        tc.TestSetup = testsetupObj;
        tc.TestExecution = teObj;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, tc);
        writer.Close();          
        MessageBox.Show("XML File created ! ");
    }
```

Now I have a requirememnt like . 
Case I
1.On click of Clone button all the controls which are grouped under Testsetup should be dynamically generated.
For which I tried to generate only two controls dynamically and code is pasted below.

```
int inputNumber = 1;

        //Initialize list of input text boxes
        inputTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
        inputComboBoxes = new List<ComboBox>();
        string dd;

        //Generate labels and text boxes
        for (int i = 1; i <= inputNumber; i++)
        {
            #region
            //Create a new label and text box
            Label labelInput = new Label();

            ComboBox comboBoxNewInput = new ComboBox();

            //Initialize label's property
            labelInput.Text = "Action";
            labelInput.Location = new Point(30,  groupBox2.Bottom+ (i * 30));
            labelInput.AutoSize = true;

            //Initialize comboBoxes Property
            comboBoxNewInput.Location = new Point(labelInput.Width, labelInput.Top - 3);

            //Add the newly created text box to the list of input text boxes
            inputComboBoxes.Add(comboBoxNewInput);                   

            //Add the labels and text box to the form
            this.Controls.Add(labelInput);

            this.Controls.Add(comboBoxNewInput);

            Label labelInput2 = new Label();
            TextBox textBoxNewInput = new TextBox();

            labelInput2.Text = "TimeOut";
            labelInput2.Location = new Point(comboBoxNewInput.Width + 120, groupBox2.Bottom + (i * 30));
            labelInput2.AutoSize = true;

            //Initialize textBoxes Property
            textBoxNewInput.Location = new Point(labelInput2.Width + 200, labelInput2.Top - 3);

            ////Add the newly created text box to the list of input text boxes
            inputTextBoxes.Add(textBoxNewInput);


            //Add the labels and text box to the form
            this.Controls.Add(labelInput2);
            this.Controls.Add(textBoxNewInput);
```

Am I taking the right approach because I find this approach a little tedious. Is there any better way to accomplish my task??

Case II
2. As you can see from TestCase class above code I have created classes and generating xml out of objects of classes.
If the controls are gnerated dynalmically then how should I modify my above code of XmlSerializer?

I treid to search alot about Dynamically generated controls in widows application. Didn't find any luck in getting the good one

Please do help me with suggestions. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: At design-time, create a `UserControl` and add the controls you need to have on it. Then at run-time, dynamically create instances of that user control and add in to your form.

Comment: Hey Reza, Thank you very much for your response. I will try doing it with UserControl.

Comment: You can open the Form1.designer.cs file and see at all the code that Visual Studio generated for you. Reading it should enlighten you on how to dynamically create the control. This will only work if you are using Visual Studio and using the default "Generate Members = true"

Comment: Hi Vikhram, I tried doing the same. For reference I have attached code above in my question you can see Case I below that is the code i tried.please let me know if its the same thing you asking me to do?